# hreflang tag for different design and different site?

Tags: meta-tags, hreflang

We are going to extend our business to a different language and brand (English, `abc.com`) rather than our local one (German, `bcd.com`). Whilst the content for both focuses on same subject, the design and site names differ. Can we safely use `hreflang` in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Since your domains are different for your English site and German site, there really is no need to use `hreflang` as covered [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) by Google. If you had a single domain for a [multilingual](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192) site that served content in more than one language, then you'd want to use `hreflang`.

Even though the two sites will focus on the same subject, you won't run into [duplicate content](http://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content) issues because English content is not considered to be the same as German content by search engines like Google, as discussed here by Matt Cutts: [Does translated content cause a duplicate content issue?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=UDg2AGRGjLQ#t=41)

One caveat to the above however is that you shouldn't use the same content for both sites that has only been translated by [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/), since it would detect that the content is the same. Instead it should be translated by a human, and as much as possible tailored to users of that language.

As a side note, it might be a good idea to specify the Geotarget for each site to Google and Bing:

[Google Webmaster Tools - Geotargeting](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en)

[Bing Webmaster Tools - Geotargeting](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/geo-targeting-your-website-b7629197)

Answer (score 0):

The [`hreflang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#attr-hyperlink-hreflang) gives the **language** of the linked resource. You can use it on *every* link (`a`, `area`, `link`). It has nothing to do with translations by itself.

The `rel` attribute gives the **relationship type** of the link. One of the [possible `rel`-keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16163402/1591669) is [`alternate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#rel-alternate). This is kind of a special keyword, as the

> […] meaning of this keyword depends on the values of the other attributes.

One special case is:

> If the `alternate` keyword is used with the `hreflang` attribute, and that attribute's value differs from the root element's language, it indicates that the referenced document is a translation.

So for *any* link on your German site to your English site, you should use `hreflang="en"`. If (and only if) the linked resource is a translation of the linking resource, use `rel="alternate"` in addition.